# Any information on BLS, BLD, HU, etc connectors

Tags: connector, specifications, documentation

There are a few similar types of connectors: BLS, BLD, HU, PHU. They are frequently encountered in electronic devices, but I couldn't find any information on them. Google only finds a bunch of places to buy them, sometimes with a picture and a short description. Where can I find more information? What do their names stand for? What company invented them, and when? Where is any documentation, specifications, or other documents? What other similar types of connectors exist? Why does any information on these connector types seem to be completely absent from Wikipedia and other informative websites?

Here are some images:

[image: BLS, BLD]
<sub>(source: [cablesandconnectors.com](http://cablesandconnectors.com/PIX/panblsxx.jpg))</sub>

[image: HU]
<sub>(source: [cablesandconnectors.com](http://cablesandconnectors.com/PIX/panmlxhuxx.jpg))</sub>

[image: PHU]
<sub>(source: [cablesandconnectors.com](http://cablesandconnectors.com/PIX/panmlxphux.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you provide at least some images?

Answer (score 2):

These connectors are most likely produced by Hsuan Mao of Taiwan. Black connectors is their 4000 series and they indeed look very similar to FCI (Berg) MINI-LATCH housings.

Comment: Welcome on the electronics stackexchange site! Thanks for your answer; if you happen to have a link to the manufacturer or the product you can edit your post or leave it as a comment. This makes your answer more useful!

Answer (score 0):

They look to be similar to [Molex KK style](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=PRODUCTS&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction) connectors with 0.1" (2.54mm) pitch.

Not sure if Molex was the very first to introduce these, but certainly one of the dominant suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

The black parts are similar to [Molex C-Grid III](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=cgrid_iii&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors) , I think the original standard for this design came from Berg (now FCI).

Spehro is right about the white items, they are copies of very popular Molex KK ranges.

It's a bit of a minefield as there are so many options and manufacturers trade names, however I think Molex is a good place to start, as most of these ranges will be stocked in depth by distributors all over the world, the difficult bit is picking the popular types, but that should not be too hard.

Here is the Molex link for the [3.96mm versions](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/listview.jsp?query=&offset=0&filter=&fs=application%3Awire-to-board&npp=20&sType=z&autoNav=&path=cHome%23%23-1%23%23-1~~f105%7C%7C332e39366d6d~~nf47%7C%7C4b4bc2ae20333936&channel=Products&key=fb_fan)  and [2.54mm](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors)

By the way, the names of the copy product don't match the Molex names.